# How to automate database deployments?

Tags: database, postgresql, deployment, dokku

I am using Dokku for simple git-based deployment for a Flask webapp on DigitalOcean. The postgres database schema is being updated as we develop, since our product relies heavily on pre-processed backend analysis, but there are no user-initiated INSERTs. I'm looking for a more automated way to update the database than to manually make a local dump, scp it to the server, and reload everything.

Does anything spring to mind?

Comment: Can't you just target the same update tool to the live server once you've validated that it works on the local testbed?

Comment: I was imagining something more like Rails-style database migrations that can be checked into version control and rolled back. I found exactly what I'm looking for-- http://flask-migrate.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: Liquibase is also worth looking at.